# Docker-compose bridge network & host remote port forwarding at the same container

Tags: docker, unix, networking, ssh, docker-compose

I'm trying to make service that can forward remote database port to container and at the same time can be accessible by alias hostname from other containers to work with them.
I am think that make all containers communicate by host network is bad practice, so i am trying to setup that configuration.
When i am triyng to add to php-fpm service network with `driver: host`, docker says
`only one instance of  "host" network is allowed`
When i am trying to set php-fpm service with this

```
networks
- host
```

Docker says that he cant find out network with this name.
When i try to define network in docker-compose by id of built-in `host`, it just cant start this container.

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  redis-data:
  home-dir:

services:
  &app-service app: &app-service-template
    build:
      context: ./docker/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./src:/app:rw
    - home-dir:/home/user
    hostname: *app-service
    environment:
      FPM_PORT: &php-fpm-port 9001
      FPM_USER: "${USER_ID:-1000}"
      FPM_GROUP: "${GROUP_ID:-1000}"
      APP_ENV: local
      HOME: /home/user
    command: keep-alive.sh
    networks:
    - backend-network

  &php-fpm-service php-fpm:
    <<: *app-service-template
    user: 'root:root'
    restart: always
    hostname: *php-fpm-service
    ports: [*php-fpm-port]
    environment:
      FPM_PORT: *php-fpm-port
      FPM_USER: "${USER_ID:-1000}"
      FPM_GROUP: "${GROUP_ID:-1000}"
      APP_ENV: local
      HOME: /home/user
    entrypoint: /fpm-entrypoint.sh
    command: php-fpm --nodaemonize -R -d "opcache.enable=0" -d "display_startup_errors=On" -d "display_errors=On" -d "error_reporting=E_ALL"
    networks:
    - backend-network
    - frontend-network

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html
    environment:
      FPM_HOST: *php-fpm-service
      FPM_PORT: *php-fpm-port
      ROOT_DIR: '/app/public' # App path must equals with php-fpm container path
    volumes:
    - ./src:/app:ro
    ports: ['9999:80']
    depends_on:
    - *php-fpm-service
    networks:
    - frontend-network
```

Network scheme (question about green line):
[image: Network Scheme]

Host works on Debian 7 (updates prohibited) and conainer works with lastest Alpine